# writing from iframe to the outside web page

Tags: jquery

HI,
I have a iframe in my web site and i need to write something in to a div outside of the iframe when a button is clicked, this is not working with the regular

```
$('#id').html("write something");
```

any ideas how to do this?
Thank you very much

Comment: Are both pages from the same domain (I know it's very likely, but I just want to make sure ;))?

Comment: Yes they are both on the same domain.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$('#id', window.parent.document).html('write something');
```

Obviously this assumes that the parent and the iframe are on the same domain otherwise you will not be able to manipulate the parent from the child neither the parent will be able to manipulate the child (if they are not from the same family :-))

Answer (score 0):

As Darin said the following will work if the iframe uses the same domain as the parent page:

```
    $('#id', window.parent.document).html('write something');
```

If the parent domain is different from the child domain you can use something like this: [easyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM#readme)

Comment: so why you duplicate the answer with Darin Answer ?

Comment: @chhameed: Because I was expanding on his answer and offering an alternative solution if the parent and child existing on different domains.